# Do employers receive any financial benefit from offering a RRSP/401K matching program?

Tags: 401k, retirement-plan, rrsp, employer-match

I understand that companies that offer RRSP matching programs may be more attractive to work for/have better employee retention, and the employers may get warm fuzzies from offering it to their employees, but do they receive any kind of direct financial benefit from doing so?

Specifically interested in Canada, but curious about the US as well if anyone has relevant info.

Comment: @yoozer8 specifcally the answer https://money.stackexchange.com/a/11065/22266

Comment: Specifically the answer https://money.stackexchange.com/a/11065/22266